# Change Icon Direction on Accordion Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr7oggLv/2/) which includes a Bootstrap Accordion embedded inside another Accordion, the issue is that the Chevron to the right does not now behave as expected.

As you can see by the code below, the chevron changes direction when `collapse` is triggered, however, now it is in an embedded accordion this doesn't appear to be the solution.

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-chevron-down").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-chevron-up").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
});
```

Comment: I think is a new feature for bootstrap collapse http://jsfiddle.net/rr7oggLv/3/
shown.bs.collapse works for all collpase but not for specific =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually prefer to do this with CSS - less messy than trying to detect which item opened/closed when you are nesting, or have multiple on a page.

1) Add the class 'collapsed' to your accordion headings if they are closed by default (bootstrap toggles this class, but if you don't have it present when the page loads, it doesn't get added until you open and then close an accordion item).

2) Get rid of the JS and add this CSS:

```
.panel-heading.collapsed .glyphicon-chevron-down {
  transform:rotateX(0deg);
}
.panel-heading .glyphicon-chevron-down {
  transition:transform .5s;
  transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

If you don't like the flip animation, just get rid of the `transition` rule, but I like to think it adds a little something.

http://jsfiddle.net/rr7oggLv/6/

Comment: Really nice method and like the addition of the flip animation, thanks!

Comment: I have a follow up query on this, if I wanted the "example 2" window to be open from the start and therefore the chevron be pointing up from the start, how would i modify the CSS to account for some chevrons being up and some being down? I'm guessing i would need to apply a second class to those that are up to start for example?

Comment: Yep, you just take the collapsed class off of the heading that should start out open, and, and add 'in' on the panel body.  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aarau7th/